# I would like the dates to appear on the X-axis and the colour category to apear on the Y-axis, Excel

Tags: excel, graph, charts, excel-2003

there is probably a fairly straight forward answer out there but I can not seem to find a solution online.

I have a table marked up like this (column names are in bold)

**audit date**  | **blindness**

10/17/2001  | red

10/17/2002  | green

10/17/2003  | yellow

10/17/2004  | unknown

10/17/2005  | red

I would simply like to make a line graph in excel, where the audit date values are the X-axis categories, and the blindness values are the Y-axis categories.

I have tried so many little tutorial's online but my graph never comes out looking correctly.  I can not get the axis the way I'd like.

PS - I am using Excel 2003

Comment: maybe show the code you are using?  If you are not doing this programmatically, then you are in the wrong place. Try superuser.com.

Comment: Ahh good call.  Only using code to export to excel, then I thought there would be an easy way for my boss to highlight, then make the graph.

Could you or someone transfer my question to superuser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will tell you how to do it:

http://peltiertech.com/Excel/Charts/ArbitraryAxis.html

P.S. I'm colorblind :-)

Comment: Thats OK, the graph would still be accessible to persons with colour deficiency. The graph I desire would not use colour to depict information, it would just have colours on the y-axis.  Check this out for an exact example of what I'm referring to. http://superuser.com/questions/273275/i-would-like-the-dates-to-appear-on-the-x-axis-and-the-colour-category-to-apear-o